# Foundation Reveal Modal Pop up going down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Foundation 5 "reveal Modal" to popup content. I nested reveal modal within a reveal modal. and there are 4 modals nested.

So, When i call first modal it shows middle in a screen very well. But when i call second modal it start going down. When i open 3rd modal it goes more down and on 4th modal it goes fully down.

Without making more confusing check this jsFiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/4eoexrhp/1/

So from that fiddle you can see that with every modal the popup going down. Any idea how can i make it in place while opening different modals?

Code is very straight forward

HTML Markup for reveal modal
        Start

```
<!-- Reveal Modals begin -->
<div id="firstModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
<p> Text</p>

<p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="secondModal" class="secondary button">Second Modal...</a></p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="secondModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
<p> Text </p>

<p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="thirdModal" class="secondary button">third Modal...</a></p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="thirdModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
<p> Text </p>

<p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="fourthModal" class="secondary button">fourth Modal...</a></p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>


<div id="fourthModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
<p> Text </p>

<p><a href="#" data-reveal-id="close-reveal-modal" class="secondary button">End</a></p>
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have the same value of top attribute for the reveal-modal divs.

A quick-fix solution is to add this to your reveal-modal css class:

```
.reveal-modal {
    top: 100px !important;
}
```

I noticed that the top attribute for reveal-modal divs gets set through js. Therefore if you hate using !important, you may try resetting the top attribute in js/jquery on click of the respective links.

I have added `top: 100px !important` to the jsFiddle that you provided, and it is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4eoexrhp/4/